# What was the controversy with Kokoro Connect?

Tags: anime-production, kokoro-connect

There were several news articles during the airing of Kokoro Connect regarding some sort of a controversy during the production of the anime. This lead to a pretty substantial boycott effort. I didn't watch the show and didn't follow the news pieces, so I don't really know the specifics, and it's hard to tell what actually happened and in what order now since the articles I could find don't describe the whole event.

Can anyone provide a relatively complete chronological account of the major events that happened in the controversy, with appropriate sources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All dates listed are in 2012. I have merely summarized the events and more detailed information can be found via the source links.

### June 24: Advanced Screening Event

Some time before this date, Mitsuhiro Ichiki auditioned for an original character for the TV series. He was invited to the screening event as "a surprise voice cast member". However, at the event, he was informed that he was actually appointed "Head of Public Relations" for the series. The original character does not actually exist.

Source: [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-09-04/kokoro-connect-staff-issues-statements-on-performer-treatment)

### September 2: Twitter

The opening theme's composer, Hajime Kikuchi, sent rude tweets to well known voice actor and singer Momoi Halko. He decided to step away from the music group (eufonius), but it's unclear whether this was truly his own action or something "forced" upon him by the label.

Source: [ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-09-08/composer-hajime-kikuchi-steps-away-from-band-eufonius) and [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=498753)

As a result (well, according to the animation studio, due to "production issues"), the opening theme was changed on the BD/DVD release of the series and for some of the episodes during the TV airing. This was probably the cause of the BD/DVD release getting delayed by a month.

Source: Two ANN articles: [One](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-09-10/all-kokoro-connect-bds/dvds-delayed-1-month) and [two](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-10-01/kokoro-connect-bds/dvds-to-use-different-opening-theme)

The linked ANN article for the screening event also mentions that Hajime Kikuchi may have made some tweets about that incident, but it does not mention whether they were apologetic or negative.

Comment: This is a good summary. Unfortunately there's probably no way to know whether all the apologies are deliberate or if they were forced.